# Como criar automaticamente via Maven arquivos específicos para deploy de cada container?

Tags: maven, tomcat, jboss, glassfish, java-ee-7

Estou trabalhando em um projeto JEE bastante complexo, que envolve a possibilidade de ser feito o deploy da aplicação para cada cliente em um container diferente.

No meu ambiente de desenvolvimento uso JBoss, porém o ambiente de produção poderá usar tanto o JBoss como GlasFish, ou mesmo apenas o Tomcat.

Estou me atualizando no assunto pois faz em torno de 5 anos que não programo para JEE, além do citados, sei que há outros que não me lembro o nome agora.

Como posso parametrizar o **Maven** para que este crie os arquivos de deployment proprietários como o `jboss-web.xml`. Além do `context.xml` para containers tipo Tomcat?

Lembrando que há dois tipos de aplicação, puramente WEB (Cliente), EAR (Cliente+Agentes).

Comment: Exatamente, onde entra o spring boot nessa história? Quanto a empacotar específico para cada container, existem algumas formas com maven, como usando *filters*, *profiles*, mover arquivos específicos por *profile*, etc. Logo mais incluo uma resposta para você.

Comment: @BrunoCésar, o Spring Boot, é uma opção, pode haver clientes menores, que irão executar a aplicação em apenas uma única estação, lamentavelmente há clientes que não querem a aplicação rodando totalmente remota pois temem que seus dados sejam usados sem autorização, em breve estarei abrindo esta aplicação para maior debate sobre opções de desenvolvimento de clientes, assim que o core estiver funcionando e aprovado (se aprovado) :D (Será Open Source, mas não Free)

Comment: Neste caso já é outro contexto, spring boot é um cara *CoC* pra evitar *boiler plate* e botar a aplicação pra rodar o quanto antes, então é outro projeto que pode usar objetos comuns, nada impede. Falar que *"o ambiente de produção poderá usar tanto o JBoss, como o GlassFish ou mesmo Spring-Boot"* é bem errôneo, uma vez que o boot não é container. Ficou um tanto confuso sua questão, ainda mais depois que citou spring, rodar um *container* spring num *container JEE* *full profile* não é trivial.

Comment: Então removo o Spring Boot, ficamos apenas com Jboss e GlasFish para simplificar a resposta.

Comment: Delfino, concluída a resposta para um exemplo funcional com vários tipos de perfis e que gera pacotes específicos por *container*. Veja se isto lhe ajuda.

Comment: @BrunoCésar, estou de saída, mas volto ainda hoje, ai dou uma olhada. Por enquanto obrigado.

Comment: Recebi um voto negativo e gostaria de saber porque para melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Para deixar registrado minhas pesquisas sobre o assunto, já que ainda não cheguei ao modelo ideal, e não tive um número de respostas para determinar a melhor, segue o link: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureJavaEEApplicationToApplyDifferentSettingsinWebxmlEtcForVariousEnvironmentsByMaven

Comment: Basicamente a mesma abordagem da resposta, não?

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas formas de se organizar o projeto com módulos maven de forma a fazer o que você precisa. Como já disto nos comentários, você pode usar [filters](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element), [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles), mover arquivos específicos por profile, etc. Vou utilizar um misto de [filters](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) e [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) em um projeto sem comportamento nenhum, apenas para demostrar esta organização.

No entanto não há algo (até então não encontrei nenhum) que crie descriptor específicos por container, como o `jboss-web.xml` ou o `glassfish-web.xml`. Então, como não há nada como isto, iremos fazer as alterações modificando propriedades e copiando arquivos específicos de acordo com o *profile* escolhido, usando apenas o plugin [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) e o `resources` do próprio build.

Irei dividir a resposta/sugestão em duas partes:

1. criação dos módulos, incluindo um EAR que terá os dois `war`;
2. criação dos *profiles* e *filters*. Os profiles estarão no módulo *parent*, não porque tem que ser assim, mas por ser gosto pessoal.

Então, teremos a seguinte estrutura de projeto:

[image: Estrutura do Projeto]

Abaixo está o resumo de cada módulo, com seu respectivo `pom.xml` contendo estritamente o necessário neste momento. Assumirei as seguintes premissas:

- `jar-project` será dependência dos dois projetos de `package` `war`;
- `ear-project` contém os dois projetos de `package` `war`;

**parent-project**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>jar-project</module>
        <module>web-project-1</module>
        <module>web-project-2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**jar-project**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jar-project</artifactId>
</project>
```

**web-project-1**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>web-project-1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>jar-project</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**web-project-2**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>web-project-2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>jar-project</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**ear-project**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <artifactId>ear-project</artifactId>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>7</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web-project-1</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web-project-2</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-project-1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-project-2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Agora vamos à construção dos [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) e [filters](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element), você pode usar só *profiles* com as propriedades, mas uso os dois apenas como exercício. Como estamos considerando três containers teremos 3 perfis e assumo o seguinte:

- `jboss-web.xml` só constará no *build* quando o [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) for `jboss`;
- `glassfish-web.xml` só constará no *build* quando o [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) for `glassfish`;
- `context.xml` só constará no *build* quando o [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) for `tomcat`;
- `tomcat` é o [profile](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) padrão;

Como dito antes, os perfis estão todos no `pom.xml` do projeto agrupador, abaixo estão apenas os trechos deles.

Perfil **jboss**:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <properties>
        <container>jboss</container>
    </properties>
    <build>
         <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/context.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*-web.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/WEB-INF</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/glassfish*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>ear-project</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

Perfil **glassfish**:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>glassfish</id>
    <properties>
        <container>glassfish</container>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <!-- esta é a parte que iremos dizer para o maven em quais arquivos ele deve usar as propriedades que estão nos filters -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/context.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*-web.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- usaremos este plugin para incluir os arquivos *-web.xml no lugar correto -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/WEB-INF</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/jboss*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>ear-project</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

Perfil **tomcat**:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>tomcat</id>
    <properties>
        <container>tomcat</container>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <!-- esta é a parte que iremos dizer para o maven em quais arquivos ele deve usar as propriedades que estão nos filters -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*-web.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/context.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Não exemplifiquei nenhum projeto com `package` do tipo `ejb`, mas você pode fazer isto (provavelmente não irá usar, por estar considerando tomcat também), ou seja, pode empacotar, por exemplo, o de `package` `jar` no `ejb` e fazer o deploy dele junto com o `EAR`, como dito no início, existem **N** formas de se organizar o projeto.

A parte de *build* do `pom.xml` também deve ser alterada, para algo assim:

```xml
<build>
    <!-- a construção terá um nome específico por container (ex.: web-project-1-tomcat) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${container}</finalName>

    <!-- execução padrão, por isto basta mvn para o tomcat -->
    <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>

    <!-- aqui é onde estão os filters com as propriedades que serão substituidas nos arquivos xml -->
    <filters>
        <filter>${filter.path}/src/filters/filter-${container}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Outra coisa é uma propriedade para referenciar nosso *filter*, então inclua isto no `pom.xml` do `project-parant`:

```xml
<properties>
    <filter.path>${project.basedir}</filter.path>
</properties>
```

E isto nos demais `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
    <filter.path>${project.basedir}/..</filter.path>
</properties>
```

Este é um exemplo de filter. Eles devem se chamar `filter-glassfish.properties`, `filter-jboss.properties` e `filter-tomcat.properties`:

```
webapp-1-context=app-1
webapp-2-context=app-2
```

Para o exemplo todos tem o mesmo conteúdo, você pode customizar conforme necessário.

Outra coisa é que você pode customizar os arquivos de configuração da forma que quiser, desde usando [filters](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element), até propriedades em perfis, pela linha de comando, fica a seu critério.

Para executar você deve fazer algo como o seguinte:

- para `tomcat`: `mvn`
- para `jboss`: `mvn clean install -P jboss`
- para `glassfish`: `mvn clean install -P glassfish`

Uma última observação é: não tem nada ir os `*-web.xml` nas outras construções, por os outros containers não iriam entendê-lo mesmo e isto serviço para todos os outros *descriptors* específicos de cada *container*.

Outras formas de serem feitas é usando o [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)(este é bem legal, pessoalmente gosto mais dele por que é menos "verboso"), o [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) ou até mesmo [desenvolver seu próprio plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html), pode ser que decida escrever um para você de forma a criar os arquivos específicos por *container*.

Não sei se consegui responder exatamente sua questão, mas espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: vou analisar sua resposta com mais calma a manha a tarde. Mas até agora pelo que ví terei que reformular minha pergunta, pois não informei o fato que terei que usar uma IDE como o Eclipse. E não há como eu criar um sub-projeto para cada container.

Comment: @Delfino em nenhum lugar fala que você precisa criar "sub-projeto" por container, são perfis do maven para cada container. Além disso, ferramentas como o maven são agnósticas quanto a ambientes como IDE. A solução demonstra (e sugere outros meios) para construções específicas para container, o que já é outra coisa.

Comment: por isso disse que vou analisar com mais calma, agora a noite não vou conseguir dar um retorno adequado a resposta, mas por enquanto vai meu voto pelo esforço como agradecimento.

Comment: Bruno, não estou me sentindo muito confortavel com a proposta apresentada, esta semana que entra irei estudar alternativas usando plugins, caso alguém queira me ajudar com uma proposta. Porém acho que minha necessidade pode estar neste link: https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: @Delfino sim, uma outra alternativa é usando este plugin, inclusive referenciado na resposta, ele também usa os *excludes* e *includes* para só ir os artefatos específicos e você pode ter vários *descriptors* também, ou mesmo uma combinação deles com o `maven-antrun-plugin`. Enfim, tem várias formas de fazer :)

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, vejo que será uma boa jornada.

Comment: @Delfino ok, qualquer coisa me avise que atualizo a resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Bruno penso que a resposta acabou ficando longa devido aos exemplos o que me assustou, e não li tudo, já que no ponto que interrompi a leitura não estava seguindo o que eu esperava ser possível com o Maven.